# How to cause difficult terrain for terrains other than land?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, terrain

In the game session last night we had a room that was filling up with liquid, and right away it became difficult terrain and then you needed to make swim checks. I was under the effects of fly so I simply kept flying above the fluid for as long as possible.

How can I make other terrain (e.g. the air) difficult and thus require increased amounts of movement?

Comment: Are "you" a DM who can control nature or are "you" a player looking for things a PC can do within the rules?

Comment: I guess both since it would be a neat ability. As a DM I could simply create something yes, but I was hoping that something already existed.

Answer (score 1):

### You make the difficult terrain affect more than a few feet above ground.

It is known that [Underwater Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/wilderness/terrain/aquatic-terrain/#TOC-Underwater-Combat)'s movement counts as difficult terrain (you move at 1/4 or 1/2 speed) if you lack *swim speed*.

But keep in mind that *difficult terrain* is not the only way to cause [Hampered Movement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/exploration-movement/#TOC-Tactical-Movement) in combat: *Poor visibility* and *obstacles* will also reduce your movement speed.

[Windstorm-strong](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/environment/weather/) winds can check a creature, which will require a strenght DC 10 (on ground) or Fly DC 20 check (if airborne) to move against the wind. It also cuts visibility by 3/4, which should count as *Poor Visibility* and thus reduce your movement speed.

[Spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/) with a **Spread** or **Burst** range should spread in all directions, including up or down from the point of origin.

> The default shape for **a burst effect is a sphere**, but some burst spells are specifically described as cone-shaped. a burst’s area defines how far from the point of origin the spell’s effect extends.
>
> **A spread spell extends out like a burst** but can turn corners. You select the point of origin, and the spell spreads out a given distance in all directions.

The finest example of a spell like that is [Web](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/web/):

> The entire area of the web is considered difficult terrain.